# How to create Dependency in POM.XML for Testlink (testlink-api-client) 2.0

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, dependencies, pom.xml, testlink

For a Research I'm working on I was required to integrate and Selenium(Java) based automation framework along with TestLink to update the testcases. Though, **I successfully managed to complete the goal**, After committing the Java Package to the framework in SVN, others were unable to use it due to an referencing matter.

Reference Link : http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/testlink-tutorial-3/

According to above link, the TestLink Client API Jars are added through as a library locally.

My current requirement and approach is to insert the TestLink Client API Jars to a newly created folder called 'libs' inside the solution and give the relative path to it as an dependency in pom.xml.

For that, I created a repository as follows with several assistance from blogs and internet.

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>lib_framework</id>
    <url>${project.basedir}/libs</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>????</groupId>
        <artifactId>testlink-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

But I was bit confused on the way of doing it as I was unable to identify whats to be given as the *groupId* for it.

1. Will someone kindly assist me on whats to be given for the groupId?
2. Do the dependency maps along with the repository if the jar files were stored the *${project.basedir}/libs* ?
3. Is there a better approach for my requirement, than what I attempted and researched on?

[image: lib folder created inside the solution(framework) and the jar file in it]
*Image Description : lib folder created inside the solution(framework) and the jar file in it*

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem as above. There is no dependency provide in Maven for `Testlink-Client-API`.

**Problem statement now :**

> How to add custom library or jar file in maven dependencies?

By following below steps I have achieved solution.

**Solution :**

1. Copy jar file at some location in project. Lets assume it is :

   `src\main\resources\jar_library\testlink-api-client-2.0.jar`
2. Now move to your `pom.xml` file path in **CMD** or **Terminal** (*mostly root folder of project*)
3. For windows user, use below command to add jar as maven dependency :

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=src\main\resources\jar_library\testlink-api-client-2.0.jar -DgroupId=com.testlink.client -DartifactId=testlink-api-client -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jarmvn install:install-file -Dfile=src\main\resources\jar_library\testlink-api-client-2.0.jar -DgroupId=com.testlink.client -DartifactId=testlink-api-client -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar`

- For Ubuntu change as per requirements and path.

**Note : It is single line command.**

4. At last, add dependency in your `pom.xml` as under and start using it :

   `<dependency>`

   ```
       <groupId>com.testlink.client</groupId>
       <artifactId>testlink-api-client</artifactId>
       <version>2.0</version>
   ```

   `</dependency>`

Enjoy !!

> **Important note : step 3 and 4 should be match in details and versions**
>
> **Advice** : Whenever system get changes , you require **to copy manually jar in .m2 folder at given path**. Here it is `.m2\repository\com\testlink\client\testlink-api-client\2.0`

Please let me know If any query.